# Rails form helper: Multiple nested models like "Article.comments" in one form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters, view-helpers

Here is the `form_with` view-helper from the Rails "Getting Started" Guide (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) for the nested Article model `Comment` or `Article.comments`:

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @article.title %>
</p>
 
<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @article.text %>
</p>
 
<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_with(model: [ @article, @article.comments.build ], local: true) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :commenter %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :body %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
 
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(@article) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

Also

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
  validates :title, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

and

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
end
```

Now I would like to know if it is possible to use the `form_with` helper or another helper or helper-combination in order to create or edit a new Article with more than one nested models like Comment, **Tag,** ... and what further models an Article may be composed of.

... which creates a sane and useful params-Hash (because my own solution with a 'fields_for' form-helper doesn't produce a desired or useful params hash.

This is how the params-hash looks like:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"BeCtYS/U6lugXzzplTEBsMXAiD0x7z28iBUblHiza379p4YqRcd+ykgd49o53oOrC8o+iPhtWnvQQHe0ugCJow==", "article"=>{"parent_article_id"=>"", "title"=>"Überschrift", "text"=>"Toller Text"}, "tags"=>{"name"=>"Rails"}, "commit"=>"Update Article", "controller"=>"articles", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"1"} permitted: false>
```

The problem is that the controller/article id is not subsumed under the `:article` key. I don't know how to fix that for strong_parameters and I don't even want to. I would prefer Rails to just function after the principle of least astonishment instead of doing hackery things to get things working.

In this case I hope it's my own ignorance and lack of knowledge regarding form-helpers that prevents Rails from generating a proper params-hash.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're looking for `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, which is [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: thanks but already added that to my model

Comment: `accepts_nested_attributes` does nest "child" model params within the parent's, so you should be getting what you asked for. Can you post your own view and controller code? Your params look very strange and I'm guessing you're not implementing the form correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Rails should be doing this as you expect.
From `accepts_nested_attributes`:

> Consider a member that has a number of posts:
>
> ```
> class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
>   has_many :posts
>   accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
> end
> ```
>
> You can now set or update attributes on the associated posts through an attribute hash for a member: include the key :posts_attributes with an array of hashes of post attributes as a value.
>
> For each hash that does not have an id key a new record will be instantiated, unless the > hash also contains a _destroy key that evaluates to true.
>
> ```
> params = { member: {
>   name: 'joe', posts_attributes: [
>     { title: 'Kari, the awesome Ruby documentation browser!' },
>     { title: 'The egalitarian assumption of the modern citizen' },
>     { title: '', _destroy: '1' } # this will be ignored
>   ]
> }}
>
>
> member = Member.create(params[:member])
> member.posts.length # => 2
> member.posts.first.title # => 'Kari, the awesome Ruby documentation browser!'
> member.posts.second.title # => 'The egalitarian assumption of the modern citizen'
> ```

The params hash you are showing *is* very strange. It looks like you're manually making disconnected fields like `parent_article_id` instead of actually using the capaibilities of `form_with` and `fields_for`.

I'd need to see *your* view and controller code to see how you've implemented `form_with` and `fields_for` to help you get these params nested the way you want.